# Scrolling is disabled in ag-grid-vue

Tags: scrollview, scrollbar, infinite-scroll, ag-grid-vue

I am working on a bit older project with ag-grid-vue version 26.2.1 and vue 2 version 2.6.14. The scrolling feature of ag-grid-vue is completely disabled. I tried to follow the documentation and did all necessary settings but couldn't resolve the issue. I am using bootstrapvue library for my html and the parent element of my ag-grid-vue component is a  element.Below are my grid settings.

````
    <div :class="['ag-grid-container', agGridTheme]">
        <ag-grid-vue ref="agGridReport" @grid-ready="onGridReady"  
                       :defaultColDef="defaultColDef" :columnDefs="columnDefsReport"
                   :rowData="tableItems" :gridOptions="gridOptions" 
                       @rowClicked="onReportsRowClickedAgGrid"
                       @selectionChanged="onCheckboxValueChanged" 
                       :paginationNumberFormatter="paginationNumberFormatter"
                       @first-data-rendered="onFirstDataRendered">
                            
               </ag-grid-vue>
        </div>

    columnDefs: [
    { headerName: ' ', field: 'checkbox', suppressSizeToFit: true, checkboxSelection: true,
                                          
                headerCheckboxSelection: true, maxWidth: 50, editable: true, sortable:false},
        { headerName: 'ID',  field: 'Id', maxWidth: 100, sort:'asc' },
        { headerName: 'Name',  field: 'Name'},
        { headerName: 'Ownership',  field: 'Ownership' },
        { headerName: 'Owner',  field: 'Owner' },
        {
            headerName: 'Actions',
                field: 'addButton',
            cellRenderer: this.buttonsCellRenderer,
            // width: 100,
            cellStyle: { 'text-align': 'left' 
                },
        

    ],
    defaultColDef: {
            editable: true,
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
            filter: true,
            flex: 1,
            cellDataType: false
    },
    gridOptions: {
            rowSelection: 'multiple',
            suppressRowClickSelection: true, // Rows won't be selected when clicked
            pagination: true,
            paginationPageSize: 7,
            domLayout: 'autoHeight',
            // rowHeight: 'getRowHeight',
            rowBuffer: 10,
            suppressHorizontalScroll: false,
            suppressNoRowsOverlay: true, // Hide the "No Rows" overlay
                        suppressLoadingOverlay: true // Hide the loading overlay
        },


@media (max-width: 768px){
    .ag-grid-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: auto !important; /* Enable horizontal scrolling */
        // display: flex !important; /* Use flexbox to allow the grid to grow and shrink */
    }
}
`
```
I want to display a grid with scroll features and I tried to make the parent container to have fixed width and height to check the scrollability but it didn't work. I tried the recommendations on the ag-grid-vue documentation to enable the scroll feature but couldn't come up with a solution.
````

Comment: Sorry, the version is ag-gri-vue 23.2.1 not 26.2.1.

Comment: It's hard to spot the problem without the code on an online editor, please share your code